# is there a way i can save user input then reuse it later in python?

Tags: python

i have this program that asks for their password and i would like to save what the user has inputted into a file then reuse it later.

```
while True:
user_input=""

FB=input("What is your Facebook password? \n ")
print("Your Facebook password is " + FB + " is this correct?")

user_input=input()
if user_input == "yes":
    print("password has been saved")
    break
elif user_input == "no":
    print("password was not saved \n")
else:
    print("i do not understand. Sorry")
    break
```

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Have you tried searching around this topic? What went wrong with the attempts from your research? Errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend storing passwords in flat file. there are many ways of storing information securely, e.g. in database. but if you're not concerned with security writing to a text file is very simple:

```
with open('secret.txt', 'a') as s:
    s.write(FB + '\n')
```

to know more check the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html